# How to get partitionId and TopicName in KafkaStream application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How do we get topic name and partition id from KafkaStream.  For any other Kafka consumer we can get topic name and partitionId like following:

```
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {System.out.printf("consumed: key = %s, value = %s, partition id= %s, offset = %s%n",record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset());}
```

Not sure how to get the record reference in KafkaStreams.

Comment: Why would you need that information?

Comment: I have written a KafkaStream application to monitor the statistics of partitions of a Kafka topics that are unbalanced.  In this statistics I need to have partitionId and topicName along with different count in the KafkaStream window.

Comment: What do you mean by "unbalanced"?

Comment: We have a use case where we have multi tenant Kafka Stream.  Partition on Kafka Stream has skewness based on partitionId.   We wrote a tool using KafkaStream to identify the topic with skewness.

Comment: My clients have written similar things, just using `GetOffsetShell`. You don't need to consume a topic to determine offset skewness

Comment: Yes we are aware of GetOffsetShell command.  But what I explained is very simplistic idea of what we trying... Our usecase is more involved... Getting Key that has partitionId skewness is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get meta data of input record via the `ProcessorContext` that is exposed in the Processor API. You can embed the Processor API in the DSL via `transform()` and similar methods.

Check out the docs for details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#accessing-processor-context

Comment: thanks for your response.  Processor API documentation is NOT very clear... Simple example of word count OK.  BUT the question is how do we do common Windowing operation in Processor API.  How do we add the features of Kafka Streams like Windowing with the Processor API...

Comment: Well, you would need to build it yourself from scratch. The DSL implementation might help to get ideas how it can be done: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamWindowAggregate.java

Comment: Thanks BUT all I wanted partition ID from the topic... For that simple metadata... I NEED to implement and rewrite the Windowing operation...

Comment: Well, your original question was about how to get partition-id, and I provided an answer. -- In your comment to asked a second question and I provided an answer. It's unclear to me how both questions relate to each other... How do you want to use the partition-id?

Comment: thanks for your response @Matthias J. Sax.  I just feel hesitant to write the Windowing logic myself in a Processor... I like the DSL implementation of windowing logic etc... It seems strange to me that to get simple metadata like paritionId and topic name etc I need to re-write whole DSL Windowing implementation...

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the DSL windowing to get the metadata and I did never say that. You asked how do to this: `BUT the question is how do we do common Windowing operation in Processor API. How do we add the features of Kafka Streams like Windowing with the Processor API...` -- it's not clear to me though, why you want to do this.

Comment: Just reading the other comments on the question: seems you want to group-by topic and partition: for this case, you just use `transform()` to get the metadata and set it as message key. `transform()` gives you a `KStream back that you can aggregate and window with the DSL afterwards.

Comment: Thanks so much!! You suggestion is extremely helpful!