# Kafka Streaming Windowing Using Processor API

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

**Problem:**  I have a usecase where I want to get topic name, partition id etc.. per window of Kafka Stream...

**What explored so far:** I found that we CANNOT get partition id from Kafka DSL API...  In order for me to get the partitionId using Kafka Windowing is to use Processor API...  I looked at the document provided by Kafka about processor API here https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#accessing-processor-context

**Question** How do we integrate this Processor API with Kafka Windowing and other Kafka streaming features?  Example above is simple wordcount...  Can we have some detail example...

Comment: This answer is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480113/how-to-get-partitionid-and-topicname-in-kafkastream-application

Comment: If the linked answer resolves your question, you might want to delete your question, or close it as duplicate?